# Linux: How do I execute a script in a way that it knows its directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script, path

I need to write a script, which would be called from any location,
but needs to run from the directory it resides in. The script should query its directory at runtime.

How can this be achieved?

Example:

- script `hello.sh` resides in `/someplace/`
- though it is called from `/other/place/`,
- the script knows (during runtime) that it resides in `/someplace`

**EDIT**
Additional question:
How's about the location of the script, but with symlink resolved?

Example:

- script `hello.sh` resides in `/someplace/`
- symlink exists to it in `/bin`
- though the symlink is called from `/other/place/`,
- the script knows (during runtime) that it resides in `/someplace`

Comment: I suggest you move this to Stackoverflow.  I think it's more related to programming than to general computing, and you might get faster and better responses there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo $(dirname $0)
```

or

```
echo ${0%/*}
```

Comment: Great, it works!

Comment: Unless the script is in your PATH and you don't specify the full path to it; in that case, $0 will not have any path information.  The best you can do then is to traverse PATH yourself.

Comment: "Unless the script is in your PATH" - I just tested this and got the correct result. The worst case is if you do `./scriptname` then you just get back `.`, but you can test for that and get `$PWD` or `$(pwd)`.

Comment: Also, if you have `readlink`, you can do stuff like `readlink -f ..` to turn relative paths into absolute ones.

Answer (score 2):

To my additional question: I found this to work:

```
echo $(dirname $(readlink $0))
```

or

```
echo `dirname \`readlink $0\``
```

**EDIT**
*Seems, this answer came at the same time Dennis Williamson commented his answer with the solution ;)*

Comment: You can (and should) nest `$()`, so this would be `echo $(dirname $(readlink $0))`

Comment: Can you explain why, please?

Comment: The second one would be parsed as
echo `dirname \` then readlink $0 then ``
It has no way of knowing that the first ` should match the fourth `.  With $( and ) it knows what matches what.

Comment: That mangled the backquotes.  It should have been
echo (backquote dirname backslash backquote) then (readlink $0) then (backquote backquote).  It has no way of knowing that the first backquote should match the fourth backquote, so it just matches the first with the second, and the third with with fourth.

Comment: Readability, nestability, reduced need for escaping, etc.: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 1):

Check out the shell variable $_

From the bash manpage:

> At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in the environment or argument list.  Subsequently, expands  to     the  last  argument to the previous command, after expansion.  Also set to the full pathname used to invoke each command executed and placed in the environment exported to that command.  When checking mail, this parameter holds the name of the mail file currently being checked.